# What is growth of a function and growth rate of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to figure out what is `growth of a function` and `growth rate of a function` means and how should I note it.

As I understand growth rate of `f(n)` is dominant term of `f(n)` when n tends to infinity. So if we have for example:
$$f(n) = 4n^2 + 5 + 7n^3$$

The growth rate of `f(n)` will be $$ growthRate=7n^3$$ where `growthRate` as I understand should be noted in some formal way.

And I have no idea what `growth of a function` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, growth rate of a function $f(x)$ means how fast the value of $f(x)$ increasing or decreasing as the value of $x$ increases. For example, if $f(x) = x$, for every unit increase in $x$, the function increases by one unit but if if $f(x) = 10x$, then for every unit increase in $x$, the function increases by 10 units.

In your example 
$$f(n) = 4n^2 + 5 + 7n^3$$
observe that for $|n| > 1$ the magnitude of $n^3$ is always greater than that of $n^2$. Hence as $n$ increases, the corresponding increase in $n^3$ will be greater than that of $n^2$. Hence we say that growth rate of this function is of the order of $n^3$ and the exact growth rate is $7n^3$. Note that when we use the term order, we are only interested in the largest power on $n$ which in this case is 3 and we are not interested in the coefficient.

**Explanation in layman's terms**: If your salary is \$8,523 per month and someone asks you what your salary is you can either say the exact amount \$8529 or you can \$8000 because compared to \$8000, the remaining amount \$529 is relatively small and you can ignore it in you day to day conversation and still give a fairly accurate answer just by saying \$8000.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: according to your explanation, dominant term of a function (without constant) is equal to growth rate of a function. Is it correct?

Comment: @NoNameYp: Yes when we ignore the constant we use the terminology ORDER of growth rate is $n^3$. But if you don't want to ignore the constant and want to be more accurate you simply say growth rate is $7n^3$. In  short, the word ORDER removes the constant. Pls check my updated explanation.